# Make field unique per user Id in Sequelize?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, unique-constraint

Scenario:

User has 3 choices, 1st choice, 2nd choice, 3rd choice. Every choice is saved in db with choice number and user id.

How to put a unique validation so there can't be TWO choice#2 for user#11.

Reading documentation it seems you are only able to put for one column like email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_user_choice ON my_table(choice_id, user_id);
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66a23/3)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("user_id" int, "choice_id" int, "comment" varchar(8))
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_user_choice ON t(choice_id, user_id);

INSERT INTO t
    ("user_id", "choice_id", "comment")
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'azer'),
    (1, 2, 'zsdsfsdf'),
    (2, 1, 'sdghlk')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
INSERT INTO t ("user_id", "choice_id", "comment")
VALUES (2, 2, 'dfgdfgh')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66a23/3/0)**:
**Query 2**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66a23/3/1)**:

```
| user_id | choice_id |  comment |
|---------|-----------|----------|
|       1 |         1 |     azer |
|       1 |         2 | zsdsfsdf |
|       2 |         1 |   sdghlk |
|       2 |         2 |  dfgdfgh |
```

**Query 3**:

```
INSERT INTO t ("user_id", "choice_id", "comment")
VALUES (1, 2, 'cvbkll')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66a23/3/2)**:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idxu_user_choice" Detail: Key (choice_id, user_id)=(2, 1) already exists.
```

Comment: not sure, what would be the outcome. Would it be unique by user# AND choice#, so there can b user#2 + choice#1 and user#3 + choice#1.. but not user#2 + choice#1 and user#2 + choice#1